# ""gjs-console" closed unexpectedly" error message

Tags: java, javascript

Mine is Ubuntu 18.4. I get the following error message frequently.

"Sorry the program "gjs-console" closed unexpectedly your computer doesn't have enough memory"

Sometimes the browser (Google chrome) freezes at the same time. Other than that I haven't experienced any problem. How to stop it?

Comment: Do you have enough space and memory? Could you add output of `df -h` and check `sudo top`